# Exclude Products from loop using woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have to exclude some products in category loop product page using woocommerce. Only that products, have specific value in meta table will be excluded. I have written below code but this is not working for me. Please somebody help me.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

      if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
      if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

     $q->set( 'meta_query', array(array(
                 array(
                     'key' => '_auction_closed',
                      'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                    )
                 )
               )
             );

    remove_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

    $meta_query = $q->get('meta_query');
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'=>'_auction_closed',
        'compare'=>'NOT EXISTS',
        );
    $q->set('meta_query',$meta_query);

    remove_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

}
```

Comment: It's working fine here. check once in your database for meta_key _auction_closed". Is it exists in postmeta table or not?

Comment: The Main purpose of this function is to display the product that don't have meta key '_auction_closed'. Some of my product have meta key '_auction_closed' but some don't have. I only have to show the products that don't have this meta key and this is not working on my end in category page using woocommerce.

Comment: yes i know the purpose of this function and it's working fine here.Display only those products don't have meta key '_auction_closed' overhere